# How to scale data in Open CV LibSVM

Tags: opencv, machine-learning

i am developing English Handwriting OCR with **OpenCV** and **Visual C++**. I use Zone based approach for feature extraction. Here I use `64×64` images.
So i have **64 features** for one sample image. My **SVM** will be **Multi-class SVM** because i have **52 classes** for both capital and simple letters.
Here is the format of feature vector.

```
Class A image1 0:0.222000 1:0.0250222 ..... 63:0.000052
Class A image2 (some float values) .... 
Class A image200 (some float values)
```

likewise i have **200 images** for both **52 classes**. When testing my current accuracy rate is **35% - 40%** only.I have read as scaling data increase the accuracy of the prediction.
But i have few things to be make clear.

1. How can i scale these feature values ?
2. Is there any function to get the matching probability of each test feature vector in **OpenCV LibSVM** (I search the **OpenCV 2.4.5** documentation, but I couldn't find this).

Can anyone explain these? , and also with some **very few code lines** if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your data is scaled somewhat already but the libsvm guys would recommend (http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf) scaling linearly to [0, 1] or [-1, 1].  If you have pixel data [0,1] probably makes more sense.
2. I don't see it either.  You can link against the C++ libsvm (http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/)  and then you have two options.  A) Train class probabilities, in which case you get those back or B) ask for distances from the decision boundary.

Comment: good point about the data being "scaled somewhat already". So just dived by 255; in fact for this case where the data is essentially binary, and the max value is not that big, you can probably get aware with no scaling.

Comment: If you divide by 255 make sure you convert to a floating point representation.

Comment: @Josh S - thank you very much for your effort and considering my question. my data are already scaled( between 0 to 1). But i need to find the matching probability somehow. I feel pure LibSVM is suits for my purpose instead of OpenCV integrated one.

Answer (score 3):

1. Take a look at [A Practical Guide to Support Vector
   Classiﬁcation](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/talks/freiburg.pdf). Basically, you should scale each dimension of your feature vector to [-1, 1] or [0, 1] (same across all dimensions). For example, for the first dimension, if you know the possible maximum and minimum values are `v_max` and `v_min` （like if it's pixel gray value, then they are 0 and 255）. Then you can compute the new feature value as `new_val = (old_val-v_min)/(v_max-v_min);`
2. This is the documentation for OpenCV SVM predict function: [`predict`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvm-predict).

   `float CvSVM::predict(const CvMat* sample, bool returnDFVal=false ) const`

   If you pass in `returnDFVal` as true, then you will get the distance to the margin as returned value. It's not a probability, but you can use it as an indicator to how good your classification is.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much for considering my problem and for your effort. I thought to use the pure LibSVM instead of OpenCV integrated one. Both are same but i feel using Pure LibSVM will solve my problem. Thank you very much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408031/scaling-for-single-instance-in-matlab-for-libsvm?noredirect=1&lq=1